# Shiny selectize-dropdown menu open in upward direction

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny

In my shiny dashboard I have a couple of dropdown menus of type [selectizeInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html). They are located at the bottom of the page, so instead of opening the dropdown menus downward I would like to open them upward.

I did find a [solution](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/403) for the `shinyWidgets` dropdown menu called [pickerInput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.3/topics/pickerInput). The solution here was to add a `css` tag:

```
.dropdown-menu{bottom: 100%; top: auto;}
```

However, this tag isn't working for `selectizeInput`. Any idea which `css` I have to add to my script?

**Edit (answer by maartenzam with example)**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # selectize style
  tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", paste0(".selectize-dropdown {
                                                     bottom: 100% !important;
                                                     top:auto!important;
                                                 }}"))),
  div(style='height:200px'),
  selectizeInput('id', 'test', 1:10, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                 options = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: By googling, I find there's an option `dropdownDirection` of `selectize.js`. However `options = list(dropdownDirection = "up")` does not work. Perhaps `selectize.js` is not up-to-date in shiny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do somethink like

```
.selectize-dropdown {
  top: -200px !important;
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the tag that I was looking for! I added a minimal reproducible example for future readers in my question. Instead of using `top: -200px`, it is better to use `bottom: 100% !important; top:auto!important;`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for this, very useful!

Leaving this here just in case someone is interested in changing the behaviour only for some `selectizeInput`'s and leave the others default (just as I was):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('#upwardId+ div>.selectize-dropdown{bottom: 100% !important; top:auto!important;}'))),
  selectizeInput(inputId = 'downwardId', label='open downward', choices = 1:10, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),
  div(HTML("<br><br><br><br><br>")),
  selectizeInput(inputId = 'upwardId', label='open upward', choices = 1:10, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process this in `onDropdownOpen` event.

```
$('select[multiple]').selectize({
  onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
    $dropdown.css({
      bottom: '100%',
      top: ''
    }).width(this.$control.outerWidth());
  }
});
```

---

In my project I used `data-dropdown-direction` attribute to specify which element should dropdown in up direction.

In template:

```
<select multiple data-dropdown-direction="up"></select>
```

In script:

```
$('select[multiple]').selectize({
  onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
    if (this.$input.data('dropdownDirection') === 'up') {
      $dropdown.css({
        bottom: '100%',
        top: ''
      }).width(this.$control.outerWidth());
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this via Selectize options.

```
$('#selectize').selectize({
    dropdownDirection: 'up',
    plugins: [
        'dropdown_direction'
    ],                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @ismirsehregal, dropping a helpful variation on this using the new `virtualSelectInput` function from `shinyWidgets`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # modify virtual select css https://github.com/sa-si-dev/virtual-select/blob/master/dist/virtual-select.min.css
  tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", paste0(".vscomp-dropbox {
                                                        position: absolute !important;
                                                        bottom: 100% !important;
                                                        top: auto !important;
                                                     }}"))),
  div(style='height:200px'),
  virtualSelectInput('id', 'test', 1:10, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
                     options = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```